# kendo grid with angular2+, Can I set focus on a textbox within the formgroup opened to edit the row? If so how?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, grid

Using the kendo grid with angular2, is it possible to set focus on a textbox within a formgroup opened to edit the row.   I have tried methods that work with angular2 forms but the kendo grid control resets focus to the first input of the form group.

This is a significant issue for my users that do heavy data entry and prefer not to use their mouse.  If there are any ways to keyboard navigate in an editable mode.  I am open to recommendations.

Comment: Facing the same issue here. Telerik says it is not supported out of the box but there is a solution they advise in [this post](https://www.telerik.com/forums/programatically-set-focus-to-specific-cell-when-grid-is-in-inline-edit-mode). Haven't tried yet.